# How to pass a variable from one qt form to other form qt form?

Tags: c++

Hello i have a problem related to passing an entered string from one form to the other form.The header file of this code has getters and setters while a private variable Username is also present.I want to pass an entered string username from this code

```
void norm_user::on_pushButton_clicked(){
login conn;
QString  Password,username;
username = ui->lineEdit_username->text();
set_username(username);

Password = ui->lineEdit_password->text();


if(!conn.connOpen2())
{
    qDebug() << "No connection to db";
    return;
}


conn.connOpen2();
QSqlQuery qry;

qry.prepare("SELECT Username, Password FROM Users WHERE Username=\'" +username+ "\' AND Password=\'" +Password+ "\'");

if(qry.exec())
{
    if(qry.next())
    {
        ui->label_check_1->setText("[+] Valid username and password");
        QString msg = "Username = " + qry.value(0).toString() + " \n" +
                "Password = " + qry.value(1).toString() + " \n" +
                "Role = " + qry.value(2).toString();

        QMessageBox::warning(this,"Login was successful",msg);

        ui->testing->setText(get_username());

       users_platform platform;
        platform.setModal(true);
        platform.exec();

    }
    else
    {
        ui->label_check_1->setText("[-]Wrong username or password");
    }
}
```

}

This is the second form of the project where iam suppose to pass the string in the qt label.How am i suppose to pass the string to this code ?

```
users_platform::users_platform(QWidget *parent ) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::users_platform)
{
norm_user c;
ui->setupUi(this);
login conn;
QString usr;
QFileInfo checkfile(path_2);


if(checkfile.isFile())
{
     if(conn.connOpen2())
     {
         ui->label_check->setText("[+]Connected to Database");
         ui->test_1->setText(c.get_username());
     }
     else
     {
         ui->label_check->setText("[!] Database not found");
     }
 }
```

}

Comment: You pass stuff by *calling functions*, *with arguments*. Add functions as needed if not already present.

Comment: i dont get it ! but i need to pass the string to other form.

Comment: Can you call a member function of the other form and pass your string to the member function?  Another alternative may be to access the widget in the other form directly and assign the string.

Comment: (QT creator)The problem is iam making a login form when a user enters the username i need that username to pass it to the other form even though i made a public variable for the first form and copying that string into it but when i use that variable in the second form for the label it shows me blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have an unnecessary [circular dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) in your code. You are instantiating an `users_platform` inside your `norm_user` and also you are creating a `norm_user` inside your `users_platform`'s [constructor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constructor_destructor.htm). I see no reason for this, because your `norm_user c` variable will not hold any usable information.

If `norm_user` is the creator of the `users_platform platform`, it should be eligible to pass any necessary information. You could simply pass it by the constructor `users_platform::users_platform(QWidget *parent, const QString& username)`. Or you could pass by a [setter](https://www.tutorialcup.com/cplusplus/getters-setters.htm). Some will argue, that this is not a good practice, but it will do the job. Unfortunately, you do a lot of things in the constructor of your `norm_user`, so this wont really work for you. Also, you could use [signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) for passing variables, but with your current design this wont really help you either.